# Where has the module spring-cloud-stream-codec gone?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to upgrade https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-jms so that we can upgrade to spring-boot 2 for our projects. There is a dependency on org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.codec.kryo.KryoCodecAutoConfiguration. Has this been moved to another module/project or been deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

`org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.codec.kryo.KryoCodecAutoConfiguration` is removed in 2.0. Starting with 2.0, Spring Cloud Stream doesn't rely on `kryo` for any message serialization. Messages are converted using regular message converters (default content type used is `application/json`). If you still want to use Kryo for serialization, the KryoMessageConverter is still provided although it is deprecated in 2.0. More details can be found out here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RC2/reference/htmlsingle/#contenttypemanagement
and https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/wiki/Kryo-Java-serialization-Notes.